# ReportViewer render not resetting for new data

Tags: c#, .net, reportviewer

I have a method that renders a report as a PDF so that it can be attached in an email.  The code is as follows:

```
private string generate_pdf_report(int ponum)
    {
        this.DataTable1TableAdapter.Fill(this.reportdataset.DataTable1, ponum);

        Warning[] warnings;
        string[] streamids;
        string mimeType;
        string encoding;
        string filenameExtension;
        string filename = "Purchase Requisition " + ponum.ToString() + ".pdf";

        byte[] bytes = reportViewer1.LocalReport.Render(
            "PDF", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out filenameExtension,
            out streamids, out warnings);
        try
        {
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create))
            {
                fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

        return filename;
    }
```

This works fine the first time, but if the user generates another report and sends an email, the report attached to the email is the first one generated, not the current one.

For example, the user opens the software, creates purchase order #3, and the PDF is generated and emailed correctly.  The user then creates a new purchase order without exiting the software, #4.  After #4 is submitted, the PDF attached to the email is from #3, like the `ReportViewer` did not clear out the previous data.

Even if the `ReportViewer` interface is used to generate a new report, it does not affect what is attached to the email.  I have tried clearing the `ReportViewer` between renders to no avail.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to correct the problem by resetting the ReportDataSource each iteration of the function:

```
        this.DataTable1TableAdapter.Fill(this.reportdataset.DataTable1, ponum);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = DataTable1TableAdapter.GetData(ponum);
        Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource rprtDTSource = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource(dt.TableName, dt);


        reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rprtDTSource);

        Warning[] warnings;
        string[] streamids;
        string mimeType;
        string encoding;
        string filenameExtension;
        string filename = "Purchase Requisition " + ponum.ToString() + ".pdf";

        byte[] bytes = reportViewer1.LocalReport.Render(
            "PDF", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out filenameExtension,
            out streamids, out warnings);
        try
        {
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create))
            {
                fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                fs.Flush();               
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

        return filename;
```